# If $x^n-3x^{n-1}+2x+1=0$, compute $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k}{x_k-1}$

Tags: polynomials, summation

> Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ be the $n$ roots of the equation $x^n-3x^{n-1}+2x+1=0$. Calculate the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k}{x_k-1}$.

Can somebody give me some tips, please? It's pretty hard to make up the sum using [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), and I think there may exist an easier method.